# Getting SQL syntax error during a function create on Jboss

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, db2

I am getting some SQL syntax error when i try to run a simple MySQL function create query . This is the query what i tried on MySQL   . This is working with Db2 . i want to run it on MySQL .

```
CREATE FUNCTION MAC_ADDR
  (
    IN M BIGINT
  ) RETURNS VARCHAR(17)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  READS SQL DATA
  BEGIN
    DECLARE TMP BIGINT;
    DECLARE RESULT VARCHAR(17) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE B INTEGER;
    DECLARE I INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    IF (M IS NOT NULL AND M > 0) THEN
      SET TMP = M;
      LOOP
        IF I > 0 THEN
          SET RESULT = ':' || RESULT;
        END IF;
        SET RESULT = SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND(TMP, 15)), 2, 1) || RESULT;
        SET RESULT = SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND((TMP / 16), 15)), 2, 1) || RESULT;
        SET TMP = TMP / 256;
        SET I = I + 1;
        IF (I > 5) THEN
          RETURN UPPER(RESULT);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN '00:00:00:00:00:00';
  END;
```

After running on the server , i am getting following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN M BIGINT) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(17)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERN' at line 1
```

is `IN M BIGINT` in MySQL ? Any syntax i am missing ? Please suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION MAC_ADDR
  (
   M BIGINT
  ) RETURNS VARCHAR(17)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DETERMINISTIC
  READS SQL DATA
  BEGIN
    DECLARE TMP BIGINT;
    DECLARE RESULT VARCHAR(17) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE B INTEGER;
    DECLARE I INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    IF (M IS NOT NULL AND M > 0) THEN
      SET TMP = M;
      LOOP
        IF I > 0 THEN
          SET RESULT = ':' || RESULT;
        END IF;
        SET RESULT = SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND(TMP, 15)), 2, 1) || RESULT;
        SET RESULT = SUBSTR(HEX(BITAND((TMP / 16), 15)), 2, 1) || RESULT;
        SET TMP = TMP / 256;
        SET I = I + 1;
        IF (I > 5) THEN
          RETURN UPPER(RESULT);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN '00:00:00:00:00:00';
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For further details on FUNCTIONS, please refer :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html

http://javajee.com/mysql-stored-procedure-and-stored-function-examples

For Function creation,no need to give IN for input parameters.
Delimiter is used to tell the MySQL client that you've finished typing in an Sql statement, unless we will get Missing semicolon error in the function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion and answer .